# Date available as Month-Yr and tried converting to proper date format with as.Date. . used format %b -%y and got NA in the variable cells

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

Original data shows Month-Yr and I converted it to date format with as.Date. I got NA in coercion. Original dates are running from Jan-87 to Dec-93. I get all original dates replaced by NA.
output from R 4.3.2.
souvenirsales$Month.Yr<-as.Date(souvenirsales$Month.Yr,format="%b-%y")

> souvenirsales
> Month.Yr souvenir.sales Monthyr
> 1              1664.81

I tried differently by changing original date format to yyyy-mm-dd and even then things did not improve. Now message is about start and end some true/false needed.

souvenirsales.ts<-ts(souvenirsales.vec,start=c("1987-01-01"))
Error in if (start > end) stop("'start' cannot be after 'end'") :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In ts(souvenirsales.vec, start = c("1987-01-01")) :
NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 0):

`ts` does not work well with `"Date"` class but we don't really need that since what you have seems to be monthly data starting in Jan 1987 rather than daily.

```
ts(11:13, start = 1987, freq = 12)
##      Jan Feb Mar
## 1987  11  12  13
```

This would also work:

```
library(zoo)

DF <- data.frame(ym = c("Jan-87", "Feb-87", "Mar-87"), x = 11:13)
DF |>
  read.zoo(index = "ym", FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%b-%y") |>
  as.ts()
```